# When "most is" and when "most are"?

Tags: grammatical-number

> Most corn seed is genetically engineered.
>
> Most people in town are unemployed.
>
> Most fish is/are seawater species?

Is there any general rule that separates where the majority part described by "most" is plural, and when is it singular? Especially, when it's describing some entity composed of parts.

Comment: Your examples use *is* for singular or mass nouns and *are* for plural, which is how *be* conjugates.

Comment: The difficulty is that 'fish' seems like a mass noun (because it is the same form in singular as in plural). But it acts as a plural noun here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate (probably several times over), but I'm too lazy to find out for sure.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/586484/2085).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about 'rule', but there is a guide and it is down to perception.

When the items can be perceived as individuals, it is plural. When the items cannot be perceived as individuals, they are literally uncountable and hence singular.

When you look in a sack of seed you don't really see individuals, and they are beyond counting, so it is *seed*. Sand, or powder, is a more extreme example. In contrast, if you have three seeds in your hand, you see them as individuals and easily countable, so it would be three *seeds* in your hand.

Compare this with, say, a sack of potatoes, where the individual potatoes are easily discerned.

As for 'fish', one explanation I have seen is that when they are animals (in other words they are alive) the plural is 'fish'; when they are food (in other words they are dead) the plural is 'fishes'. This explains why we have *all the fish in the sea* but *five loaves and two fishes*.

There are alternative explanations, of course.

People is inherently plural - the singular is 'person'.

Comment: "People" is inherently plural when  not used to describe an ethnic group, in which case it's singular, eg: _[A People and a Nation: A History of the United States](http://www.amazon.com/People-Nation-History-United-States/dp/0495916226/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1352722877&sr=1-1&keywords=A+People+and+a+Nation)_, Volume I. Mary Beth Norton, Carol Sheriff, David W. Blight, Howard Chudacoff, Fredrik Logevall. **Fishes** is an alternative plural in AmE; it's probably slightly dated & academic. Ngrams shows many titles about live fish with both spellings.

Comment: Yes. People can be used to label a population.  Well done, but I think we all know that already and it is not relevant to the question as "Most people in town are unemployed." is obviously not using *people* in that sense. Any more ah-buttery?

Comment: "Ah-buttery"? Maybe it's related to "Ah, but..."? My comment was related not to the OP's sentence about _people_ but to your comment about the inherent singularity of the lexeme _people_. I don't make as many assumptions as some of the posters here about what "we all know" because I have no idea what we all know. I'm often pleasantly surprised by what I learn from other posters: that means I don't always know even what I do and don't know. If I don't know that, then how can I be as sure as you are about what "we all know". What's your secret?

Comment: @Roaring Fish ('s answer): Very true about the 'is it countable' connection with count- and mass-noun usage. Tricky ones are **peas** (_Would you like less peas?_ I think is more common hereabouts than the _fewer_ version - especially with mushy peas.) **beans** (especially the small ones), and **bacon and eggs** (_I must eat less bacon and eggs._) _Confetti_, though a plural noun (and _a confetto_ may be used for a sweet, I believe), takes singular concord.

Answer (score 4):

*Seed* in this instance is an uncountable noun and so it’s treated as singular: *Most corn seed is . . .*  *People* and *fish*, by contrast are plural nouns. *People* has no singular form. The plural of *fish* is sometimes *fishes*, but here it is the same as the singular. It follows that you need to write *Most people in town are . . .* and *Most fish are . . .*

Comment: My answer now edited in consequence.

Comment: Sorry to add a complication, but it's important. Some nouns can be used as count _or_ non-count nouns, and then, if the plural and singular forms are identical, one has to decide whether a non-count noun (usually taking singular agreement) or a plural is involved. _Fish_ is, in fact, one of these nouns: Most fish (/es) **are** salt-water species. BUT: Most of the **fish** landed at Swiftwood **is** sold abroad. Generally, agreement is logical, but _the police_ **are** _making inquiries_ contrasting with _the church_ **is** _meeting later nowadays_ seems to argue for greater church unity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I believe that "complication" deserves to be an answer. I'd upvote it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I think you should also add "Most of the **fish** landed at Swiftwood **are** sold abroad." This is also grammatical and possible: "I gave away most of the **fish** I caught today" looks at the fish as individual fish, so it's a count noun and plural, just as in your Swiftwood sentence, in which **fish** can be either non-count singular or count plural. I don't think there is any inherent logic in the Swiftwood sentence that demands either a singular or a plural; either one will do, IMHO. What do you think?

Comment: Obviously one couldn't consider the count-noun usage impossible in that sentence, but, as Roaring Fish (!) says below, it's a matter of perception, and the mass-noun usage is more likely here. I'm comparing with 'Most of the beef produced at Buffalo Springs goes for export'. If you want a cast-iron non-count usage, 'Most of the fish in my small pie is salmon'.